# ls -l with some modifications

Tags: bash, ls

I wanted to do some changes to the ls -l command.

First, I wanted to remove the first "total X" line as I don't use it.

Then, I wanted to show directories topmost. (Or, more precisely, sort according to type.)

Third, I wanted to sort according to name in cases of identical type.

This would be almost trivial to write in a script or functional language, or even in C, but I got inspired by something I read that you should not write new stuff for everything, but rather combine the tools you have. Some hours (!!) later, I came up with this:

```
ls -l | tac | head -n -1 | sort -k 1.1,1.2 -k 9
```

Feeling a bit silly, it seems to work. But:

Slower:

```
real 0m0.009s
user 0m0.008s
sys 0m0.008s
```

instead of ls -l:

```
real 0m0.003s
user 0m0.004s
sys 0m0.000s
```

No colors! (With ls -l, dictionaries are blue, etc.)

So, if you know of a better way, shoot :)

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, this seems to do what I wanted, and it is much faster than my solution! I didn't know ls had so many options; my mistake.

    ls -l --group-directories-first --sort=extension --color=always | tail -n+2

Comment: Instead of posting answer you like in comments, you could mark it as accepted.

Comment: Ok, another challenge for you guys -- how do you preserve the `ls -l [folder]` functionality, i.e. so you can type `lsl my_dir` (if `lsl` is the alias for the modified `ls -l` command as above)?

Comment: The answer lies in these two questions: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30925/in-bash-when-to-alias-when-to-script-and-when-to-write-a-function?lq=1 and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34065/alias-in-bashrc-doesnt-seem-to-accept-an-argument?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`man ls`, I mean really, try it.

For 2nd, 3rd and no colors

```
$> ls -l --group-directories-first --sort=extension --color=never
```

If you need colors you should use `--color=auto` or `--color=always`.

For the 1st question there is a [duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61177/whats-the-easiest-way-to-remove-the-total-size-line-from-the-output-of-ls), for example.

Actually, you can remove first line with `awk`:

```
awk '{ if ( NR > 1 ) print }'
```

So resultant command looks like

```
$> ls -l --group-directories-first --sort=extension --color=always | awk '{ if ( NR > 1 ) print }'
```

Comment: No, he wants `--color=always`, because his problem is that `auto` disables color when output is not terminal (which is the case with pipes). (isn't it `man ls`?)

Comment: I'm not sure if `awk` is more efficient than `tail -n +2`. Well, +1 nonetheless.

Comment: How do you usually test a command for efficiency? I only know of `time`, and that gave me the following for the `tail` and `awk` solutions. But, as this is just one sample, I'm not saying that any solution is better than the other.

`real 0m0.005s
user 0m0.004s
sys 0m0.004s

real 0m0.005s
user 0m0.012s
sys 0m0.000s`

Answer (score 3):

`ls -l --group-directories-first -X --color=always | tail -n +2`

- --group-directories-first – Kind of obvious
- -X – Sort by extension
- --color=always – Even output colors when not writing to a tty (which we aren't because we are piping to `head`)

Comment: You even didn't check this command. Your `head` didn't remove first line, actually.

Comment: Could've corrected that minor mistake instead of wasting your rep on downvoting my otherwise fine answer.

Answer (score 0):

As for colors, you can use `ls --color=yes`.